# Ignore <input> tags with HTTP/S when removing protocols

Tags: php, regex

I run a PHP script in WordPress that removes the `http:` and `https:` protocols from all the links, [this is the full code](https://github.com/factmaven/remove-http/blob/48657ec5b711aeaa83779c301b0ed75fe286f9e9/remove-http.php), but here's the section that strips the protocols:

```
# If 'Relative' option is selected, remove domain from all internal links
if ( $this->option == 2 ) {
    $website = preg_replace( '|https?:\/\/|', '', home_url() );
    $links = preg_replace( '|https?:\/\/' . $website . '|', '', $links );
}
# For all external links, remove protocols
$links = preg_replace( '|https?:\/\/|', '', $links );
```

This works as intended. However, it also removes the protocol in text fields like so:

[image]

I'm trying to update my regex to ignore any `<input>` fields so that it doesn't remove protocols. Particularly ones with the `value=http:` or `value=https:` [From my tests](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jwU):

```
<input type="url" value="http://example.com">
```

I've come up with this pattern:

```
<input(.*)value=["\']https?:\/\/
```

But I'm not sure how to implement this regex to skip over any `<input>` field that match this logic. I've tried the following logic, but it didn't work:

```
# Skip input fields with links
if ( preg_match( '|<input(.*)value=["\']https?:\/\/|', $links ) ) {
    return $links;
}
# If 'Relative' option is selected, remove domain from all internal links
if ( $this->option == 2 ) {
    $website = preg_replace( '|https?:\/\/|', '', home_url() );
    $links = preg_replace( '|https?:\/\/' . $website . '|', '', $links );
}
# For all external links, remove protocols
$links = preg_replace( '|https?:\/\/|', '//', $links );
```

Comment: please write the html or php code for the row that has that <input>, to understand much better. Is it possible?

Comment: @JustMe Added. You can see it in the [PHP tester link](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jwU) that I've included.

Comment: As always with `HTML`, consider using a parser (eg. `DOMDocument` instead).

Comment: @Jan I did resort to DOMDocument with some help, [see this previous repo version](https://github.com/factmaven/remove-http/blob/557ffde8d04e90a3c505e00a4ac52a229a1089e6/remove-http.php), but it was eventually causing issues in WordPress' admin panel. So I switche

Comment: Easy. `$links = preg_replace( '~<input\b[^<]*\bvalue=["\']https?://(*SKIP)(*F)|https?://~', '//', $links );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970), this is the working regex:

```
/<input\b[^<]*\bvalue=[\"\']https?:\/\/(*SKIP)(*F)|https?:\/\//
```